# Can we uninstall multiple extensions via Magento2 component manager at the same time?

Tags: magento2, component-manager, uninstall-module

Can we uninstall multiple extensions via **Magento2** component manager at same time?

NOT composer via commandline. Component manager accessed from Magento2 admin panel. There is a dropdown menu against each extension/componenet, that gives uninstall option. But you can only select 1 at a time it seems, and there is no checkbox option to select multiple.

Or do we need to uninstall them 1 by 1?

It Seems to be not having ability to select multiple extensions and uninstall at once.

I am facing the issue of dependency on each other when trying to uninstall individually.

Comment: did my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have exact idea that we can uninstall them simultaneously with the composer command or not but We can uninstall the **Magento** extensions simultaneously with the **Magento** commands.

The best approach would be first disable them. We can forcefully & simultaneously disable all of them with the below command from the root directory of your **Magento** using the terminal or command prompt:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Module1 Vendor_Module2 Vendor_Module3 -f
php bin/magento mo:d -f Vendor_Module1 Vendor_Module2 Vendor_Module3
```

Then we can run the below command to uninstall them one by one

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall Vendor_Module1
```

If it is again causing any issue with the dependency at the time of uninstall also then try with the forcefully by simply adding -f into the command.

> Note: Delete the generation folder & run the below command after
>   uninstalling the modules
>
> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```

Comment: Somebody has edited my question to read composer manager instead of component manager...... It is the component manager accessed from Magento2 admin panel I am looking to use, not command line.

Comment: It was you that edited my question........

Comment: Yes I have edited your question but it was composer manager only you can see my edits from the link given below your question. I just made the question more generic & elaborated so that one can understand

Comment: through component manager you can't uninstall multiple modules simultaneously as because from there you can't give the commands to be execute forcefully. better you should go with the command line

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, trying to avoid doing by command line, but will have to I guess. Thanks for your comments and replies.

Answer (score 0):

List out all your extensions and remove them from your composer.json file and run following command :

```
composer update
```

It will remove all extensions and dependency at once.

Comment: Somebody has edited my question to read composer manager instead of component manager...... It is the component manager accessed from Magento2 admin panel I am looking to use, not command line.